# Presenter object in MVP(Android) getting null object reference error

Tags: java, android, callback, mvp

I am using MVP. My activity contains a Listview. I am initializing the presenter in my Activity's on Create method and then call an interface method using that presenter object to get data and set listview adapter.

My issue is when presenter object is used in any onClick listener then working perfectly but when I used it directly then it gives NullPointerException on Presenter object.

Here is my code snippet :

This is my Activity :-

```
public class EmployeeListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EmployeeContract.View {

private static final String TAG = EmployeeListActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView listView;
private EmployeeContract.GetPresenter presenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_employee_list);

    presenter = new EmployeePresenter(this);    //--> Presenter inialization
}

@Override
public void initView() {
    try {
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
        presenter.getEmployees(listView);     //--> interface method calling (Here I got exception.)

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                presenter.listViewClick(position);    //--> Same thing working perfectly here
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
        ErrorLog.saveLog(getBaseContext(), TAG, methodName, e.getMessage(), String.valueOf(e.getCause()));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    presenter = new EmployeePresenter(this);
}
```

}

Help will be appriciated. Thank you in advance.

**Updated** 
Here is my Error Log
`01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.myfirstexamplemvp.contract.EmployeeContract$GetPresenter.getEmployees(android.widget.ListView)' on a null object reference
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at com.example.myfirstexamplemvp.view.EmployeeListActivity.initView(EmployeeListActivity.java:35)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at com.example.myfirstexamplemvp.presenter.EmployeePresenter.initPresenter(EmployeePresenter.java:40)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at com.example.myfirstexamplemvp.presenter.EmployeePresenter.<init>(EmployeePresenter.java:34)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at com.example.myfirstexamplemvp.view.EmployeeListActivity.onCreate(EmployeeListActivity.java:28)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6582)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2532)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
01-29 16:11:54.709 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
01-29 16:11:54.710 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
01-29 16:11:54.710 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-29 16:11:54.710 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
01-29 16:11:54.710 28540-28540/com.example.myfirstexamplemvp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)`

Here is My Presenter :-

```
public class EmployeePresenter implements EmployeeContract.AddPresenter, EmployeeContract.GetPresenter, EmployeeContract.EditPresenter {

private EmployeeContract.View view;
AddEmployeeModel model;
SqliteController controller;

public EmployeePresenter(EmployeeContract.View view) {
    this.view = view;
    initPresenter();
}

private void initPresenter() {
    model = new AddEmployeeModel();
    controller = new SqliteController((Context) view);
    view.initView();
}

@Override
public void getEmployees(final ListView listView) {

    List<AddEmployeeModel> list = controller.getEmployeeList();

    ArrayList<String> empname = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (list.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            empname.add(list.get(i).getFirstName() + " " + list.get(i).getLastName());
        }
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>((Context) view, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, empname));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please post the error logs? And are you aware that you're creating your Presenter twice (in `onCreate` and `onResume`) ?

Comment: Where you calling initView method? It seems that initView() is called before the onCreate()

Comment: @Heitor I guess it's called by the presenter itself on initialisation? Would maybe explain why `presenter` is null

Comment: @Eselfar I guess you're right.

Comment: @Eselfar Yes I created Presenter twice because of resolve this issue. It is work for me to get data and set adapter but still in catch block NullPointerException raised.

Comment: @Heitor initView() is called in Presenter class's constructor when Presenter inialized in Activity's onCreateView method.

Comment: If I'm correct, `presenter` is assigned when the constructor is fully called. It means when you call `initView` from the constructor, `presenter` is not assigned yet as the constructor hasn't finished is process. That's why you get the NPE

Comment: Yes, I think this is the issue. So @Eselfar how can i solve this issue.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class EmployeeListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EmployeeContract.View {

private static final String TAG = EmployeeListActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView listView;
private EmployeeContract.GetPresenter presenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_employee_list);

    presenter = new EmployeePresenter(this);
}

@Override
public void initView(List<Employee> employees, Presenter.Callback callback) {
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    EmployeesAdapter adapter = new EmployeesAdapter(this, employees);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            callback.onClick(position);
        }
    })
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //presenter = new EmployeePresenter(this);
}
```

**Into the Presenter**

```
public EmployeePresenter(EmployeeView view) {

    List<Employee> employees = ...; // get the list of employees
    Callback callback = new Callback(){
        void onClick(int position){
            listViewClick(position);
        }
    }
    view.initView(employees, callback);
}


public interface Callback{
    void onClick(int position);
}
```

Comment: Some classes have the wrong name based on your updated code but it's the general idea. I'm using a callback so the view doesn't need to call the presenter to manage the click

Comment: So this callback is in Presenter's constructor.

Comment: Is instantiated in the constructor, yes. `Callback` is an interface. You can name it `PresenterClickListener` or whatever you want. I've defined it in the Presenter class but you could declared it in your `EmployeeContract` or in a separated java file.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: I could have used the OnClickListener directly instead of creating a new interface, but I don't want the Presenter to have directly access to any `View`

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is Violating MVP.your Presenter should not contain any android code.that's the power of MVP for easy testing.

**1-** **initialize your listView inside init() method including setting the adapter.**

```
public void initView() {
listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
adapter = new EmployeesAdapter(this, employeesList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        presenter.listItemWasClicked(position).
    }
})
}
```

**2-** **create an interface call it EmployeeData.**

```
public interface EmployeeData {
void add(Employee employee);
Employee getEmployee(int position);
int getSize();
}
```

**3-** **inside your adapter implement EmployeeData**.

```
{

//.....adapter methods

@Overrride
public Employee getEmployee(int position){
return myEmployeeList.get(position);
   }
     //.. other methods.
}
```

**4-** **inside your presenter**

```
   private EmployeeData empData;
    public  EmployeePresenter  (View view,EmployeeData empData){
    this.empData=empData;
    //... other init
    }
 @Override
 public void listItemWasClicked(int position){
 Employee emp=empData.getEmployee(position)
  }
```

**5-** inside your activity in `onCreate()` for example, initialize your Presenter.

```
employeePresenter=new EmployeePresenter(this,listAdapter);
```

**Note :** just dont forget to call `initView()` before creating the presnter

Comment: I'm not using Custom Adapter, I just used ArrayAdapter. And thank you for your response but i already solved my issue. :)